# React Native FB App install deep link issue

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-fbsdk

My FB Deferred deep link is: **einee://free_marilyn_monroe=true**.
Clicking on Install in the test ad (when the app is already installed) works fine.
However, when the app is not yet installed and clicking on the FB ad Install button which takes the user to the App Store, the deep link is not found when the app launches.

This is my code in React Native to detect the deep link:

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if(url){
        if(url.includes('free_marilyn_monroe=true')){
            // Deep link detected code
        }
    }
    // ...
```

This is my AppDelegate.m code:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "SplashScreen.h"
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <react-native-branch/RNBranch.h>

@import GoogleMobileAds;
@import Firebase;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];

  // Uncomment this line to use the test key instead of the live one.
  // [RNBranch useTestInstance];
  [RNBranch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions isReferrable:YES];
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"Einee"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                           didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  [SplashScreen show];
  [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
  [GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"ca-app-pub-3594094751431969~9145980369"];
  return YES;
}

// Respond to URI scheme links
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  if (![RNBranch.branch application:application openURL:url options:options]) {
    // Facebook scheme click detect
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
  }
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *restorableObjects))restorationHandler {
  return [RNBranch continueUserActivity:userActivity];
}

@end
```

Am I detecting the deep link wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have used url scheme for deep linking, suggest to use universal linking to handle the case when the app is not installed. Checkout the difference between two [here](https://medium.com/@abhisheknalwaya/react-native-deep-linking-for-ios-and-android-d33abfba7ef3).

Comment: What about if it's a web redirection (a website automatically calling https://my-url.com for example) and not the user directly clicking on a button ? Because if I click on the link, the deep links works well, however in the first case (with no user interaction), it's opening on safari/chrome, deeplink dont work